# Copy text with newlines to clipboard :Python

Tags: python, newline, clipboard, pyperclip

I want to copy text with newlines to the clipboard using the following code.

```
import pyperclip
numbers=''
for i in range(200):
    numbers = numbers + str(i) + '\n'
pyperclip.copy(numbers)
```

After execution the clipboard should contain:

```
0
1
2
.
.
200
```

But after I run the program and paste in Notepad.
I see

```
012345....200
```

All in a single line. :(
I use Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10

Comment: try using `'\r\n'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're pasting into microsoft notepad. In this case you should use `\r\n` (windows style) instead of `\n` only (unix style)

If you paste into [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) it will treat the newline character unix style, and you will see it separated like you want.

If you want to be OS independent then use [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep)